# I cant call web service in j2me app

Tags: mobile, java-me

I have develop a j2me app which calls .net windows based web-service.  
Its working good in emulator and nokia phones but not working in samsung and micromax.  
May be this app can not call web-services in some devices.  
Its very useful if any one can answer me.

Comment: Add some more details. Is there an Exception on Samsung and Micromax devices?